# is there a way to enter the values of a table in Matlab GUI and do some calculations

Tags: matlab

*I want to write a code for transport problems, so i have to create a table that show destinations and sources, but i need the user to enter the values of this tables . i have wrote  the code in Matlab, the user need to enter a matrix for COST as the tables , A as the supply and B as demand,
So my objetif is to allow the user to enter all of them in one small app or in MATLAB GUI to send it later*

```
Cost=input('entrer la matrice totale du cout ');
```

A=input('entrer le vecteur du stock');
B=input('faire entrer le vecteur de demande ');
% code for finding the solutions

-

---

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation and tutorials for App Designer: https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/app-designer.html